# Creating moving mouth in JQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

How do I create a mouth that opens and closes on certain event (say clicking a button)
For simplicity sake, lets say the mouth is like a screen muncher.

Problems:

1. I need to get the upper and lower jaws somewhere in the middle. How do I make the two move simultaneously?
2. What will happen to the chin (the left and right border of the screen muncher) as the teeth come together? If I don't make them resize automatically, they will exceed the lower jaw when the jaw is closing. How do I make them resize automatically?

Comment: What are you tried? Please, post some code, nobody will write down all your code, but will help you to debug it

Comment: You can do that with only jquery, but if you really want to do that nice, do it with raphael.js and vector animations.

Comment: I have not yet started writing the code... I am not expecting anyone to write the code for me either, but just if you could tell me the logic behind doing the 2 things... i can start workin on d code

i will surely check raphael.js...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try making complex css to make teeth and jaws can be made from divs with background. Then it is possible to animate css using jquery, but i'd say it is a quite difficult task only with jquery. Here's a link to jquery animate function.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate

Comment: This isn't really an answer.